# Need help in refreshing the page after submit

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an web application following the 3 tier architecture.When i am hitting on submit button data is storing in database but not showing response message like "Record submitted successfully" and fields are not refreshing. Here is my code:

```
protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsValid)
            return;

        NewuserBAL NUB = new NewuserBAL();    

        string UserName = TxtUserName.Text;
        string Password = PWD.Text;
        string EmailId = Email.Text;

        try
        {
            NUB.newinsert(UserName, Password, EmailId);
            Response.Write("<b>New User Created Successfully</b>");
            TxtUserName.Text = "";
            PWD.Text = "";
            CnfrmPwd.Text = "";
            Email.Text = "";
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;

        }

        finally
        {
            NUB = null;

        }


    }
```

Thanks,
Masum

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using Response.Write, set a label such as labelResults to display the outcome. Response.Write is not going to show up in the proper place in your rendered HTML.